# Writing Tests for Background Processes (like background jobs)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit4

I have a web application built using Spring which contains some jobs.

A typical job is to run through the database, get a list of modified customers, generate a file and FTP it. My question is, how to go about unit testing in this job?

Should I only write unit tests for each "step" of the job, like:

- Test for the method which fetches the modified customers.
- Test for file generation code.
- Test for FTP'ing the code.

But in this case, I will miss the "integration" test case for the above job. Also, Emma reports there is untested code in form of the job.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unit testing is actually testing only one class at a time. That means you have to mock the dependencies. Spring is great for that.

I would advice Mockito to do the mocking. It is a marvellous tool, and you will learn TDD which is also a way to write beautiful code.

Integration test is another topic and requires another strategy.

Testing against the database is done by extending AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests. You will find examples on the net. In general you also use an in memory db to make those tests (h2 is good for that). It can be done in the unit test phase.

Generating the file can be done as unit test. You generate files and verify the proper content. Or errors...

For the FTP part, I would say it's more part of an integration test, unless you can spawn an FTP server from your build script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an unit test for each step. Maybe you'll need to mock some methods.

And then, you can write an integration test to validate the whole, but maybe you'll need to stub some parts (like the FTP server, using an embedded FTP server in your test).